# How to map one csv file with another of slightly different data in Java? CSV1 has Fname, Lname, weight, occupation. CSV2 has Name, weight, occupation

Tags: java, collections

I have two CSV files.
CSV1 has columns Fname, Lname, weight, occupation. 
CSV2 has columns Name, weight, occupation.
Both have 3 entries (rows) and all have same Fname and Lname.

I want to map them in Java or Groovy such that same names in both files output on console or in a new file as Fname;Lname;weight;Occupation. ';' is delimiter used.

Thanks.

Comment: What is Name in the first file?

Comment: @Star Provide your two sample CSV file ,then explain the use case with example.

Comment: SO is not the homework resolving resource. Come here with your code attempts which have some particular problem

Comment: csv1 file has 
Fname Sam, Lname Doherty, Weight 60, Occupation Engineer
csv2 file has 
Name Sam Doherty, Weight 60, Occupation Engineer.

Now console O/P needs to be something like Sam;Doherty;60;Engineer

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code with a quick and dirty (and not A+ material) work since you gave us nothing to go off of...

You should create a POJO to hold the data from CSV1. Collect each of those data objects into a list, and iterate over the list to write to CSV2

```
/**
 * POJO represents one entry in the CSV1 file
 */
public class Person
{
    private String fName_;
    private String lName_;
    private String weight_;
    private String occup_;

    public Person(String fName, String lName String weight, String occup)
    {
        // Set each private member in this class with the value passed into this constructor
    }

    public String getFName()
    {
        return fName_;
    }

    // Getters for each private member here
}
```

Then the implementation logic would be something like...

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Path csv1 = Paths.get("C:/Users/haqpah/csv1.csv");
    Path csv2 = Paths.get("C:/Users/haqpah/csv2.csv");

    String csvFileAsString = new String(Files.readAllBytes(csv1));

    int endIndex = csvFileAsString.indexOf(",");
    String fName = csvFileAsString.substring(0, endIndex);

    csvFileAsString = csvFileAsString.substring(endIndex + 1); // removes the first value and comma from the String

    endIndex = csvFileAsString.indexOf(",");
    String lName = csvFileAsString.substring(0, endIndex);

    csvFileAsString = csvFileAsString.substring(endIndex + 1); // removes the next value and comma from the String

    // Do the same for weight
    // Do the same for occupation

    Person person = new Person(fName, lName, weight, occup);

    // Figure out how to collect all the Person objects you make
    List<Person> personList = ...;
    for(Person person : personList)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuidler();
        sb.append(person.getFName() + ", " person.getLName().....);

        Files.write(csv2, sb.toString().getBytes()); // Figure out how to append instead of create new
    }
}
```